# Android - Get all Alarms set in Clock application? (There might be multiple third party clock application)

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-alarms, android-2.3-gingerbread

I want to write application which displays all the Alarms and Timers set in my device.

Lets take this scenario,
**Assumption**: In my device there is one system Clock application and I downloaded 2 third party clock applications.

Now lets say, I set 3 Alarms in system clock application and 2 Alarms for each other third party application.
So Now I have total 7 (3+2+2) Alarms set.
I want list of all those alarms in my single application. How do I get that list? I searched in Alarm Manager but not helpful.
Please Help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the AlarmManager doesn't help you for this task - it just enables developers to schedule different tasks at a given interval (and repeating, too).

You would need to check if the single applications do actually share their information by utilizing a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). If that's the case you would be able to get their data.

So sadly there is no unified way for this.

Comment: But how do we know third party app will use same database for sharing Alarms data? Is there any specific Android guideline that says Alarms should use specified database?

Comment: No there isn't - you'd have to get the apk files - unzip them & check the manifest. If thats not possible for you - contact the developers and just ask ;)